# Linux add keyboard input delay before displaying characters

Tags: linux, keyboard, input

I'm looking for a way to add a delay before typed characters are displayed. Similar to how older computers and keyboards used to behave.

That means, I want there to be a time-lag between the input registering and the input being displayed. This doesn't have to be the exact approach used in the solution. It's just a means to visualize the desired behavior.

I am using Arch Linux.

If this is acheivable through [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/) that solution would be an acceptable answer.

**EDIT [7.19.21]:**
I could also simply be looking for sending the key signal on KEY UP as opposed to KEY DOWN.

Comment: How old do you mean by "older"? Computers and keyboards from 20 or 30 years ago _didn't_ behave like that.

Comment: (Unless of course you're talking about typing across a slow network connection, like Telnet or BBS over dial-up links... which is something that can be laggy at times even today.)

Comment: Yea that's a good point. At least with my 12-15 year old thinkpads there seems to be a very very slight, microsecond delay when typing things in the terminal. I don't like my computer out pacing me.